# Bad math environment delimiter

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I am using the math block to write mathematics equations in RMarkdown. Here is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krYFA.jpg)

And then i meet the error：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqlMZ.jpg)
How should deal with it.

Comment: You can either omit the $$ or omit the begin/end equation. Just start with `$$x=1$$` to get a feel for how it works.

Comment: You should not use `$$...$$`. Use either `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` or `\[...\]` depending if you want a number or not, but never use `$$...$$`.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score -2):

Consider using `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` or `\[` and `\]` instead. `$$` and `$$` are deprecated (was previously used in Tex)